# SQL Selecionar item de maior valor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Estou utilizando a base de dados NorthWind, e quero selecionar a categoria que possui o maior número de itens cadastrados. Consegui listar o ID da categoria e a quantidade de produtos que esta possui com o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT CategoryID, COUNT(ProductID) AS 'Produtos por categoria'
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID
```

E o retorno foi

`CategoryID - Produtos por Categoria
1                12
2                12
3                13
4                10
5                 7
6                 6
7                 5
8                12`

Gostaria de saber como selecionar o ID que possui o maior número de produtos por categoria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você ordenar DESC terá os maiores números de produtos por categoria:

```
SELECT TOP 1
      CategoryID, 
      COUNT(ProductID) AS 'Produtos por categoria'

FROM Products

GROUP BY CategoryID ORDER BY COUNT(ProductID) DESC


CategoryID - Produtos por Categoria
3                13
```

Apenas um resultado maior!

Comment: Legal, funcionou. Mas preciso pegar só o CategoryID 3 no caso, eu tentei um tal de "Limit" mas não funcionou...Tem alguma ideia de algum comando que me permita pegar apenas o maior?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 , você terá apenas o primeiro resultado! Mas se tiver mais de um resultado igual como o 1, 2 e 8, só virá um

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!!!